# What could cause my Carrier furnace fan to sometimes stop running?

Tags: hvac

I have a Carrier system: FURNACE 58UVB080; AC 24APA530, CONTROLLER SYSTXCCUIDO1-B, approximately 7 years old. New filter, impeccable condition.

I was initially told by the licensed installers that the fan runs all the time, unless the system is shutdown and as far as I know this has been the situation since installation.  In the last 2 weeks I have noticed when the A/C is on the fan sometimes stops for a few minutes and then it starts again.  It is easy to tell because the house becomes very quiet and I have not noticed that before.  The original installer firm has inspected the system and they cannot find out what is wrong but in my opinion the system is not running properly.

I cannot figure out how to resolve this.  I am no expert but I think it is the controller.  I cannot keep trying different "techs" until someone figures it out.  I cannot even find out a number to contact Carrier.  Does someone have any hints what could be wrong, please?

Answer (score 2):

In the manual of the Carrier Weathermaker 8000, even if the fan is switched to ON, it will stop blowing for about 30s when there is a "call for heat". p.14 4a of the 58TUA manual.

Answer (score 1):

First determine if this is a blower problem or an A/C problem.  You mention "when the A/C is on the fan sometimes stops for a few minutes."  If you switch your thermostat to "FAN ON" with "COOL OFF" does the blower still stop for a few minutes every once in a while even though the A/C compressor is not running?  If so, then you have a blower problem.  Periodic stopping for a few minutes and restarting is unlikely to be a controller failure and is more consistent with the blower motor shutting off on thermal overload.

If your blower has been running 24/7 for 7 years, then it has many hours of operation on it and it could be worn out.  With the power disconnected, you should carefully inspect the blower.  When spun by hand, it should spin freely for many revolutions and no significant drag should be noticeable.  If it is at all stiff, then the bearings have failed and the blower motor needs to be replaced.   If the bearings are good, then check the blower run capacitor with a capacitance meter.  The capacitor should be at least 90% of its labeled value.  If not, then it must be replaced.  If you are able to safely check the system while running, then measure the amperage consumed by the blower motor and compare that to the motor nameplate.  The measured reading should typically not be more than about 80% of the nameplate.  If you measure more than 100% of the nameplate, then the motor will definitely cycle on its thermal protection.  This test must be performed with the furnace cover in place.  If your furnace plugs into a nearby 110v outlet then you can measure amperage for the whole unit when the blower is on, using a "Kill-A-Watt" meter or similar.  Nearly all the unit's current draw will be the blower motor.

In case you do not want your blower to run 24/7 in the future, it should be possible in a typical residential installation to select FAN AUTO/ON at the thermostat.  Selecting "FAN AUTO" should cause the blower to run only when the system is actively heating or cooling.

Answer (score 1):

Your description strongly resembles that of a defrost cycle.  For air conditioning, this should not occur unless there is some other problem.  But if frost forms on the evaporator (indoor unit), then stopping for a few minutes and reversing heat/cold to heat the indoor until will clear the frost and ice buildup.  Turning the air circulation off improves the effectiveness of the heating evaporator so that it can get back to cooling sooner.

The source of frosting could be impeded airflow—usually the air filter needs cleaning.  Or it could be a crushed or disconnected duct, too many dampers closed, excessive moisture introduced somewhere, etc.

If all else fails, try getting the correct number to call for information from 1-800-379-6484 shown [here](http://www.carrier.com/commercial/en/us/service/operate-service-and-protect/24-by-7-support-and-service/).